# Yii2 multiple models in one form js validating

Tags: forms, validation, yii2

I have two fileds, that are uses two different instances of the same model class.

[Test Case Video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/N2L5Fho0m6cKprnrHkyotgs6s0bDikRqRJPKJR3WfWvqrtCTFiFgXbkIIvu1m7Qr/file)

```
$form->field($billing_address, 'zip', 
[
    'selectors' => [
        'input' => '#billing-zip',
        'container' => '#billing-container',
    ],
    'options' => ['id' => 'billing-container'],
])->textInput(['maxlength' => 11, 
               'name'=> 'Billing_Address[zip]', 
               'id'=>'billing-zip']); 

//Shipping
$form->field($shipping_address, 'zip', 
[
    'selectors' => [
        'input' => '#shipping-zip',
        'container' => '#shipping-container',
    ],
    'options' => ['id' => 'shipping-container'],
])->textInput(['maxlength' => 11, 
               'name'=> 'Shipping_Address[zip]', 
               'id'=>'shipping-zip']);
```

When I finish filling fields, errors are shown for only fields that has errors.
But when I push submit, **if one of zip fields has errors**, error appears **for all zip fields**

```
public function rules()
{
        return [
            [['zip'], 'string', 'max' => 23],
        ];
}
```

Comment: post your model rules.

Comment: done, added video to show the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this in your controller:

```
    if( Model::loadMultiple($model_array, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($model_array) && $model->validate()){
        //your stuff
}
```

where $model_array are an array of models

```
$model_array['model1'] = new YourModelClass();
$model_array['model2'] = new YourModelClass();
```

[Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html)

Comment: The problem not in controller, but in JS validation.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#client-side-validation) about validation? have you enabled client validation?show us your code, please, if you want some help

Comment: The code is above, in first message. Client validation aint works proprly. As you see there are 2 same fields from one model, and if one fields hasnt passed validation, the second field shows same error

Comment: Can we see Controller code? because the two things are 'related'. Have you try my solution? Both Validation (client-side and server-side) are related to the controller. ValidateMultiple 'call' Validators Class witch contains clientValidateAttribute function.(example StringValidator.php)

Comment: Im validating each model separately, like standart $model->validate() && $model->save()

Comment: Ok that's the error, try my solution and always works fine

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/N2L5Fho0m6cKprnrHkyotgs6s0bDikRqRJPKJR3WfWvqrtCTFiFgXbkIIvu1m7Qr/file